# Replace Text using jQuery without removing children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change this text:

```
<body>
<p class="server_info">
         GT 64 ms <b>|</b> Time:

         <span id="serverTime">4:21:26</span>
         <span id="serverDate">11/03/2014</span>
</p>
</body>
```

to

```
<body>
<p class="server_info">
         GT 64 ms <b>|</b> Server Time:

         <span id="serverTime">4:21:26</span>
         <span id="serverDate">11/03/2014</span>
</p>
</body>
```

How can I change just the text?

I used this

```
$(".server_info").text(function(i,v) { 
   return v.replace("time ", "Server time: "); 
});
```

but the result was this: (inside span tags were removed)

```
<p class="server_info">
    GT 64 | Server time: 4:42:02 11/03/2014
</p>
```

I want change the text `Time` to `Server Time` only without removing this:

```
<span id="serverTime">4:21:26</span>
<span id="serverDate">11/03/2014</span>
```

Comment: Do you want change just `GT 64 ms <b>|</b> Time:` or the `#server_info` full html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the html() function instead of the text() function. This will keep the span tags in place:

```
$(".server_info").html(function(i,v) { 
   return v.replace("Time", "Server time: "); 
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/f5C9J/

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to do this with javascript, then wrap it to a span is good idea.

```
<p class="server_info">
         GT 64 ms <b>|</b> <span id="time">Time</span>:

         <span id="serverTime">4:21:26</span>
         <span id="serverDate">11/03/2014</span>
</p>
```

Then use the replace method.

Or you have to append the other two elements again:

```
var serverTime = $('#serverTime');
var serverDate = $('#serverDate');

$(".server_info").text(function(i,v) { 
   return v.replace("time ", "Server time: "); 
}).append(serverTime).append(serverDate);
```